# Sometimes Informatica gets successful runs, sometimes it gets error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: sql-server, odbc, informatica

We have some workflows that work in our development and test environments, using the same ODBC credentials to pull data from the same sql server source. When we run jobs over and over, they're always successful in dev and test. When we run jobs in our prod server, they succeed or fail at around 50-50 chance with no changes to anything. When the jobs fail, they get the error below.

How are these jobs sometimes succeeding and sometimes failing when no changes are occurring? If it can find the data source sometimes, I am baffled by why it can't find the data source other times.

`READER_1_1_1> RR_4036 Error connecting to database [
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [user_name] and connection string [connect_string].].
READER_1_1_1> CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Wed Jul 05 15:21:49 2017]
READER_1_1_1> BLKR_16001 Error connecting to database...`

Comment: It sounds like there is an always on availability group for your production environment and not for your dev and test. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue persists if the user has no permission to access odbc.ini or you might have missing/additional entries in odbc.ini.  This will fail your workflows always. Not sure, you say it is successful some times and fails some times. May be database would temporary gone down at that moment. Pleas check with your dba to get the stats for the database, so that you can identify the issue clearly

Thank you

Comment: We found out that there are two informatica servers used for loadbalancing, and only one of the servers had the necessary ODBC.ini entries - which explains the near 50-50 nature of the error